# Create new file from templates and moving file to server other with bash script

Tags: bash, templates, configuration, template-engine

I create to default conf files nginx default.conf bellow and move the files created to the desired server .

Exam:

1. File default.conf

> ```
>  server { 
>      listen       192.168.1.1:80;
>      server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
>      access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
>      root         html;
>      }
> ```

2. Create conf with template and replace IP list:

> ```
> server { 
>     listen       192.168.1.2:80; (Server recevice conf is 192.168.1.2)
>     server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
>     access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
>     root         html;
>     }
> ```

3. That my idea using import variable :

   #!/bin/bash

   cat <<END
   this is a template
   with $foo
   and $bar
   END

then call it like so:

`foo=FOO bar=BAR ./template`

4. If you have any other ideas .Can you tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want (not tested).

First, all in one script with the template embedded:

Shell script `make_conf_file.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

export CONF_FILE=${1}
export TEMPLATE_IP=${2}
export TEMPLATE_PORT=${3}
export TEMPLATE_SRVR1=${4}
export TEMPLATE_SRVR2=${5}
export TEMPLATE_ACCESS_LOG=${6}

cat <<END > ${CONF_FILE}

server { 
    listen       ${TEMPLATE_IP}:${TEMPLATE_PORT};
    server_name  ${TEMPLATE_SRVR1) ${TEMPLATE_SRVR2};
    access_log   ${TEMPLATE_ACCESS_LOG} main;
    root         html;
    }

END
```

Then run as:

`./make_conf_file.sh /tmp/f1.conf 192.168.1.2 80 domain1.com www.domain1.com logs/domain1.access.log`

Or, if you want to use externally define template files:

template.dat:

```
server { 
    listen       TEMPLATE_IP:TEMPLATE_PORT;
    server_name  TEMPLATE_SRVR1 TEMPLATE_SRVR2;
    access_log   TEMPLATE_ACCESS_LOG main;
    root         html;
    }
```

Shell script `make_conf_file.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

export CONF_FILE=${1}
export TEMPLATE_FILE=${2}
export TEMPLATE_IP=${3}
export TEMPLATE_PORT=${4}
export TEMPLATE_SRVR1=${5}
export TEMPLATE_SRVR2=${6}
export TEMPLATE_ACCESS_LOG=${7}

sed "s/TEMPLATE_IP/${TEMPLATE_IP}/" ${TEMPLATE_FILE} | \
sed "s/TEMPLATE_PORT/${TEMPLATE_PORT}/" | \
sed "s/TEMPLATE_SRVR1/${TEMPLATE_SRVR1}/" | \
sed "s/TEMPLATE_SRVR2/${TEMPLATE_SRVR2}/" | \
sed "s/TEMPLATE_ACCESS_LOG/${TEMPLATE_ACCESS_LOG}/" \
> ${CONF_FILE}
```

Then run as:

`./make_conf_file.sh /tmp/f1.conf template.dat 192.168.1.2 80 domain1.com www.domain1.com logs/domain1.access.log`

Comment: In this case I have a new example edit only TEMPLATE_IP from list:

192.168.1.2,
192.168.1.3,
192.168.1.4,
192.168.1.5,

Do not run to launch each command line .

Comment: Please explain. Are you saying you want to run the command once and generate 3 files with the different IP for each one? Please identify which values would be fixed for all the files then I can suggest a alternative.